# Relation Between Eigenvalues of a Matrix and its Real Part

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ complex matrix. The real part of $A$ is $\frac{A^H + A}{2}$. What is the relation between the eigenvalues of $A$ and $\frac{A^H + A}{2}$? I know that the eigenvalues of $A^H$ are the complex conjugates of $A$'s eigenvalues.
In fact there are some inequalities. We know that eigenvalues of hermite matrices are real. So $A_r=\frac{1}{2}(A+A^H),A_i=\frac{1}{2\mathrm{i}}(A+A^H)$ are hermite matrices. Write their eigenvalues as $ x_1\le x_2\le\cdots, \le x_n;y_1\le y_2,\le\ldots\le y_n$;  Our homework is that all eigenvalues $a+b\mathrm{i}$ of $A$ satisfies $ x_1\le a\le x_n,y_1 \le b \le y_n$.How can I prove it?

Comment: Many authors use $A^*$ to mean the conjugate transpose of $A$.  Is that the sense in which you are using this notation?  I'm having difficulty reconciling that with the claim that $\frac{A^* + A}{2}$ is the "real part of $A$".

Comment: @hardmath Yes. I am using $A^*$ to refer to the conjugate transpose of $A$, which can be decomposed as $\frac{A^* + A}{2} + i \frac{A-A^*}{2i}$, where the first term is identified as the real part $A$, the second term being the imaginary part.

Comment: Thanks.  Usually when we say that something is the "real part" it works out to be a real-valued entity.  That does not hold here (as the posted Answer shows).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $A$ is normal, the eigenvalues of $\frac{A + A^{*}}{2}$ are the real parts of the eigenvalues of $A$. If $A$ is not normal, there isn't any nice relation. For example, if

$$ A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 2\varepsilon \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} $$

then the eigenvalues of $A$ are zero but the eigenvalues of

$$ \frac{A + A^{*}}{2} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & \varepsilon \\ \overline{\varepsilon} & 0 \end{pmatrix} $$

are $\pm |\varepsilon|$.