# On the imaginary and real part of the eigenvalues of a real normal matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A\in\mathbb{R}^{d\times d}$ be a real [normal matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_matrix).

We can write $A=\frac{1}{2}(A+A^T)+\frac{1}{2}(A-A^T)$.

Can we show that the real part of $A$'s eigenvalues are the eigenvalues of the symmetric $A+A^T$ and the imaginary part of $A$'s eigenvalues are the eigenvalues of the skew symmetric $A-A^T$?

---

It is claimed in [another post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2234535/relation-between-eigenvalues-of-a-matrix-and-its-real-part) that "the real part of a normal matrix $A$'s eigenvalues are $A+A^T$", however, there is no proof, and there is no claim on what happens with the imaginary part of the eigenvalues. Furthermore, it concerns complex normal matrices, I'm hoping the real case has a simpler proof.

Comment: The symmetric part is diagonalizable with real eigenvalues simply because it is symmetric. The antisymmetric part is $i$ times a Hermitian matrix, so it is diagonalizable with purely imaginary eigenvalues. Normality implies that the symmetric and the antisymmetric parts commute. Two commuting diagonalizable matrices are simultaneously diagonalizable. In other words, they share a basis of eigenvectors. I think putting all those pieces together gives you the claim.

Answer (score 6):

This can be seen as a consequence of the [spectral theorem for normal matrices.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem#Finite-dimensional_case) We note that because $A$ can be written in the form $A = UDU^*$
where
$$
D = \pmatrix{\lambda_1 \\ & \ddots \\ && \lambda_n}
$$
with $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n$ complex, $U$ is unitary, and $A^*$ denotes the conjugate-transpose of $A$, we have
$$
\begin{align}
A + A^T &= A + A^* = UDU^* + (UDU^*)^* = UDU^* + UD^*U^* 
\\ & = U[D + D^*]U^*
 = U \pmatrix{\lambda_1 + \bar \lambda_1 \\ & \ddots \\ && \lambda_n + \bar \lambda_n}U^*
\\ & = 
2 U \pmatrix{\operatorname{Re}[\lambda_1]\\& \ddots \\ && \operatorname{Re}[\lambda_n]}U^*.
\end{align}
$$
We see something similar with the skew-symmetric part.

Comment: That was simultaneous answers. :)

Answer (score 5):

One direct way is say $A\in \mathbb{M}_n(\mathbb{C})$ and $A$ is normal. There exist a unitary $U$ with $U^*AU=\text{diag}(a_1+ib_1,\ldots, a_n+ib_n)$

$A=URU^*+iUGU^*$ where $R=\text{diag}(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ and $G=\text{diag}(b_1,\ldots,b_n)$. $A+A^*=2(URU^*)$ and the imaginary part $UGU^*$.